# Force HTTPS on entire site except 1 directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, https

I have this `.htaccess` file right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It redirects everything on my site to HTTPS, which is great, however, I want the /example directory to never be in HTTPS, I want it to always be HTTP.

How could I accomplish this while having the rest of the site be HTTPS?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]` should not have the `[OR]`

Comment: [Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider reading **the SO Tour**. it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)